# ExtJS multi-select combo box

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using ExtJS 2.3.0 and am looking for a combo box that allows mulitple selection, i.e. the equivalent of

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="langs">
  <option value="">Groovy</option>
  <option value="ct1">VB</option>
  <option value="ct2">Lisp</option>
</select>
```

I've looked through the [API docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/yui-ext/docs/) and found a ComboBox class, but can't see how to turn on multiple selection.

### Update

I chose [this](http://www.figtreesystems.com/ext/ext-ux/2.0/Multiselect/Multiselect.html) 3rd party component, though [this one](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?69090-Ext.ux.form.SuperBoxSelect-as-seen-on-facebook-and-hotmail) looks a lot fancier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ExtJS forum lists at least a few possibilities but they're plugins:

[Multiselect combo boxes](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?67647-Ext3-MultiSelect-ComboBox)

Comment: Surely the core set of components must include some kind of multi-select combo?

Comment: I'm not sure...I'm still an ExtJS newbie myself...but when I googled it, the result seemed to indicate that you need a plugin.